# Deflate of inflated differs from original packet for zlib

Tags: android, perl, zlib, deflate

I have an application that produces some encoded mixed string-binary packets :
`ecbd07601c499625262f6dca7b7f4af54ad7e074a10880601324d8904010ecc188cde692ec1d69472329ab2a81ca6556655d661640cced9dbcf7de7befbdf7de7befbdf7ba3b9d4e27f7dfff3f5c6664016cf6ce4adac99e2180aac81f3f7e7c1f3f227ecd5f7707cf6ff76bfcfc7efe9f000000ffff`
(this one is outgoing)
So, by footer I see it's zlib(deflate). I can fully decode incoming packet just by adding "789c" header, but this one is a problem.

This code:

```
use Compress::Zlib ;

$string ="789cecbd07601c499625262f6dca7b7f4af54ad7e074a10880601324d8904010ecc188cde692ec1d69472329ab2a81ca6556655d661640cced9dbcf7de7befbdf7de7befbdf7ba3b9d4e27f7dfff3f5c6664016cf6ce4adac99e2180aac81f3f7e7c1f3f227ecd5f7707cf6ff76bfcfc7efe9f000000ffff";
# Converting to string
while($string =~ /(\w\w)/) {
    $str = $1;
    $string =~ s/$str//;
    $value .= chr(hex($str));
}
$output = $value;
my $x = inflateInit( )
   or die "Cannot create a inflation stream\n" ;
($output2, $status) = $x->inflate($value) ;
    print "status:$status - error\n" if $status != Z_OK and $status != Z_STREAM_END ;
    print "out:".(uc unpack 'H*', $output2); print "\n";
```

Returns me:
`out:0105303030303018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

It doesn't look right, like some info was changed to zeroes. And if I try to delfate the same way this ouput I have
`789c62643500010986910d00000000ffff`
But not the original packet. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is valid, though very inefficient, partial deflate stream consisting of a dynamic block and an empty stored block. There is no block marked as the last block, so it is an incomplete raw deflate stream.

There is no assurance that recompressing decompressed data will give you the same compressed stream back.

What you have is part of a raw deflate stream. You should be using the `-MAX_WBITS` (-15) parameter to `inflateInit()`. As opposed to prefacing with a zlib header. There is no zlib trailer, so you will get an error without that parameter.

It ends with an empty stored block (which can be seen in part as the `0000ffff` at the end), which indicates that whoever made it wanted that part to end on a byte boundary, so it could be transmitted in its entirety. It presumably would be followed by another.

Your stream is a correct raw dynamic deflate block followed by an empty stored block, which occupies the entire 118 bytes. I don't know what compressor made that, but it did so very inefficiently in that it used a dynamic block type with a large amount of overhead for a very small amount of data. That much smaller raw deflate partial stream you got back, `62643500010986910d00000000ffff`, correctly uses a static block with fixed codes and almost no overhead. It decompresses to the same thing.